# Distance of two points - csv file

Tags: python, math

I have a csv file with few records :

[image]

If there is 1 line the function counts correctly. But if i add another records (like in the picture) I have an error:

[image]

How can I avoid it?

This is my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\KLSAJDo\Desktop\Projekt.csv') 


p = [(data['x_start']), (data['y_start'])]
q = [(data['x_end']), (data['y_end'])]

print (math.dist(p, q))
```

Comment: Please share some more code, especially the import of the CSV file.

Comment: Have you had a look at the [requirements for `math.dist()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.dist)?

Comment: Is there any solution to this?